# Should the R confidence interval match up precisely with my calculated confidence interval?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

For the data set (in thousands), 153, 146, 132, 164, 172, 159, 149, 166, 161, a 90% confidence interval for the population mean price was to be calculated.

My confidence interval was (149097.01, 162458.55).

When I calculated it on R, I used t.test(x, conf.level = .90).

The interval given by R was (148225.7, 163329.9).

Is this discrepancy acceptable? I don't think I made any mistakes with my math. Thanks.

Comment: In R, I got $( 148.2257, 163.3299)$ in thousands. My guess is you didn't carry enough decimal points of accuracy through intermediate steps. Maybe your number from a t table doesn't have enough decimal places. (Might try using R just for that much.) For such a simple  procedure, I doubt there are differences in formulas btw text and R. You show none of your computations, so I can't troubleshoot what you did. Maybe these discrepancies don't lead to different interpretations, but I wouldn't want to use your results for anything important until the discrepancy is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show explicitly what does t.test compute

```
> a <- c(153, 146, 132, 164, 172, 159, 149, 166, 161) * 1000
> n <- length(a)
> s <- sd(a)
> m <- mean(a)
> error <- qt(0.95, df = n-1) * s/sqrt(n)
> m + error
[1] 163329.9
> m - error
[1] 148225.7
```

So most likely you have either made a mistake or used a different formula.

Comment: But is t.test(x,conf.level = .90) correct to use?

Comment: You might like to include what formula did you use in your post.

Comment: In R, `qt(0.95, df = 9)` returns1.833113. First thing to check: How does that compare with what you got from your t table? // Your use of R is not in doubt. (Verified twice now.)

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.